# Merge When Matched - Update Set Using Query Result

Tags: sql-server

I need to merge rows from a table on a linked server to a table on another. There are quite a few columns; is it possible to update set the target to the source using select?

```sql
MERGE [TABLE] AS TARGET
USING [TABLE] AS SOURCE
ON TARGET.Id = SOURCE.Id
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET
--Replace target row with source row
WHEN NOT MATCHED 
--Insert
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE
--Delete
```

Is there a better way to replace the row than the update set route I'm taking? Is it possible to update set the target to the source using select?

Comment: An `UPDATE` (even in a `MERGE`) always requires writing out source and target columns; there's no "match this by name for me, will you" shortcut. Incidentally, be wary of using `MERGE` in combination with linked sources; it can be convenient, but performance can vary wildly depending on what the optimizer estimates for rows affected and whether it decides to pull the source to the target, or the other way around. For something as simple as this, I'd always prefer separate statements (in a transaction if necessary), and that's assuming we shouldn't be using replication to begin with.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thanks for the advice. I'll do it how you suggested.